# Goodness of fit calculated on modified Spearman coefficient

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, spearman-rho

I have been using regression models where the most interesting predictions lay in top highest X% (say 20%) predictions. Moreover, the best trained model has to correctly maintain the relative ranking of these top 20% predictions: how can I tune a modified goodness of fit measurements to select among different models?
I was thinking about a modified Spearman's coefficient focused on top-ranked 20%. Would it be sound?